# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after using function

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access

Here the code :

```
- (void)addAnswerWithNumber:(NSString *)numberAnswer
{    
    UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"roundBlue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton setTitle:numberAnswer forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.enabled = YES;
    aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0];
    aButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    aButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [dropableZone addSubview:aButton];
    [buttonList addObject:aButton];
    [aButton release];
    [aButton release];
    if ([buttonList count] > 0) {
        dropHereLabel.text = @"";
        [self repositionRoundButton];
    }else
    {
        dropHereLabel.text = @"Déposez votre ou vos Réponse(s) ici";
    }

}

- (void)repositionRoundButton
{
    int yPos =  ((890 / 2) - (([buttonList count] * (37 + 10)) / 2));

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];


    for (int i = 0; i < [buttonList count]; i++) {
        UIButton *aButton = [buttonList objectAtIndex:i];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(yPos, (90 /2) - (37/2) , 37, 37);
        yPos = yPos + 47;
    }  
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)removeAnswer:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *aButton = sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < [answerList count]; i++) {
        AnswerView *answer = [answerList objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([[aButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:answer.number]) {

            [answer.backGroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"qcmBlueButton.png"]];
            [answer setStateToNull];
        }
    }


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    aButton.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [buttonList removeObject:aButton];
    [self repositionRoundButton];
    [aButton removeFromSuperview];
    [aButton release];
}
```

I've a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); 
when I click on the button create with - (void)addAnswerWithNumber:(NSString *)numberAnswer.

Do you see a problem in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: You are releasing  aButton  two times ,try after remove  one release statement.

Comment: Can you add the code line where you are calling - (void)addAnswerWithNumber:(NSString *)numberAnswer?

Comment: you should only release `aButton` once inside `addAnswerWithNumber`. Also, in `removeAnwer` you shouldn't release `aButton` (you might even need to retain it until the animation is over).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't `release` `UIButton * aButton;` two times in `- (void)addAnswerWithNumber:(NSString *)numberAnswer`.

I advice to remove `retain` call when you are creating `aButton` and remove all `[aButton release];` as your object will be `autoreleased`.

Also you need to remove in any case line `[aButton release];` from method `- (void)removeAnswer:(id)sender`.

Comment: Actually - it looks like it's being released three times - there's one more right at the end.

Comment: My bad this a noob question :(


other question :

Does NSMutableArray removeObject
and UIView removeFromSuperview
release the object?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, both of these method release object. And when you add - they retains it. So all will be ok!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are over - releasing `aButton`. You only `alloc` it once, so you only need to release it once.

Enabling NSZombies will help to pinpoint such errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested you are over releasing the button object. Just remove the retain in the line

```
UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
```

so that it becomes `UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`
This is an auto-released object so you don't need to release them. Hence remove both the statements that releases `aButton`

Also you dont own the `aButton` in the `removeAnswer` method so do not release the button their either.

I suggest you take a look at the [Apple Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) reference